# I get an IndexError that index type is not suitable but I have typecasted the index using the int() function. Can anybody help and explain?

Tags: python, numpy, image-processing

The below program is for scaling using first order interpolation.
I am reading an image, deleting the rows and columns and then trying to rescale the image through averaging the pixel values.

The line corresponding to the error is shown below. The code also contains a mouse handler which determines the area that will be modified after the click.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import sys
#Global Declaration
img = cv2.imread("lenna.png")
maskSize = 100
gap = 4
#Callback function
def clickAndScale(event, y, x, flags, param):
    if event==cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN:
        output = img.copy()
        for i in range (x, x+maskSize): #maskSize is for the area to undergo change after mouse click 
            for j in range (y, y+maskSize):
                output[i][j] = temp[i][j]
        cv2.imshow("Interpolation", output)


#Body of the code
height, width = img.shape[0:2]
scaleDown = np.zeros((height//gap, width//gap, 3), dtype=np.uint8)
k, l = 0, 0
for i in range(0, width, gap):
        for j in range(0, height, gap):
            scaleDown[k][l] = img[i][j]
            l += 1
        k += 1
        l = 0     
temp = np.zeros((height, width, 3), dtype=np.uint8)
k, l = 0, 0

for i in range (0, width, 4):
    for j in range (0, height, 4):
        k, l, m = i, j, gap+j
        for t in range (0 ,2):
            for n in range (0,2):
                var1 = int((l+m)//2)
                var2 = int((m+gap)//2)
                temp[k][var1] = int((temp[k][l]+temp[k][l+m])//2) #This is the line which causes the error
                temp[k][var2] = int((temp[k][m]+temp[k][gap])//2)
                m /= 2
            k, l, m  = i+gap, j, gap+j 
        k, l, m = i, j, gap+1    
        for l in range (j , j+gap+1):
            for n in range (0, 2):
                var1 = int((k+m)//2)
                var2 = int((k+gap)//2)

                temp[var1][l] = (temp[k][l]+temp[k+m][l])//2
                temp[var2][l] = (temp[k][l]+temp[gap][l])//2
                m /= 2
            m = gap+j

cv2.imshow("Image",img)
cv2.setMouseCallback("Image", clickAndScale) #Mouse Callback function
cv2.waitKey(0) 
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: What's this a guessing game?  "The line corresponding to the error is shown below."  Which line?????

Comment: When using a multidimensional array like `temp`, we prefer to see index syntax like `temp[k, var1]`.